# How to remove shipping Address option from registration, guest option etc in opencart greater then 2.0

Tags: opencart

I am looking to remove shipping Address or delivery address option from registration, guest in opencart 2.0 and above version but shiping method should be there because i want billing address to be the shipping address without extra field

I tried to implement by these two tutorials in my opencart checkout.tpl file but i am not able to find the code below one

```
$('#shipping-address .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');
```

can anybody guide is this right one or for OC above 2.0 is there any othere way to do so

http://ravishwebdesigner.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-remove-checkout-step-2-step-3.html

http://rricketts.com/how-to-remove-disable-step-4-shipping-method-from-opencart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to \catalog\view\theme\Your template\template\checkout\checkout.tpl

**find the below code and comment it or you can remove it**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>


          </div>
        </div>
```

You will find the below code in two place replace it

```
<?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-shipping-address .panel-body').html(html);

                        $('#collapse-shipping-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');

                        $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-address\']').trigger('click');

                        $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
                        $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');
                        $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                <?php }
```

**replace with this**

```
<?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-shipping-method .panel-body').html(html);


                    $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-method" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');

                    $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-method\']').trigger('click');

                    $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
                    $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');
                    $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            <?php }
```

Comment: Its working. I like to also remove steps 4,5 i.e Delivery Method & Payment Method from checkout page in opencart 2.x. So, can you tell me what changes has to been done in following file 
`\catalog\view\theme\Your template\template\checkout\checkout.tpl`

Comment: Great one! you remove the shipping address step without losing the record. The correct way.. thanks @kundan-singh

Answer (score 4):

Go to each product and changes it's "required shipping" from YES TO NO. You will find that 2 steps from your checkout is gone.

Comment: great hack to avoid the shipping drop-menu

Answer (score 2):

there are lot of method due to less time i m posting this, i wll improve nxt time

Go to
\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\checkout.tpl  line 373 approx

```
 <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-shipping-address .panel-body').html(html);

                        $('#collapse-shipping-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');

                        $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-address\']').trigger('click');

                        $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
                        $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');
                        $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                <?php }
```

Replace with

```
   <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-shipping-method .panel-body').html(html);


                    $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-method" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');

                    $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-method\']').trigger('click');

                    $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
                    $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');
                    $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            <?php }
```

Comment: i am looking to remove the shipping address option i just want my checkout page flow should be like this **1.guset or register>>2.billing address>>3.shipping method>>4.payment method>>5.confirm order**

Comment: Its working. I like to also remove steps 4,5 i.e Delivery Method & Payment Method from checkout page in opencart 2.x. So, can you tell me what changes has to been done in following file 
`\catalog\view\theme\Your template\template\checkout\checkout.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button-payment').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

On payment_method.tpl if you have only one payment method.

Its works for opencart 2.0